Why is instantiating core::time::Nanoseconds unsafe?
I was strolling through core::time and was surprised at the implementation of Nanoseconds.
Why does instantiating it require an unsafe block?
I understand the comments regarding the range restrictions of Nanoseconds (must be < NANOS_PER_SEC) but how does unsafe help here in this case?
If I copy the code into a custom crate (except the compiler internals, that are unstable):
#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Hash)]
#[repr(transparent)]
struct Nanoseconds(u32);

impl Default for Nanoseconds {
    #[inline]
    fn default() -> Self {
        // SAFETY: 0 is within the valid range
        unsafe { Nanoseconds(0) }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let nanos = Nanoseconds(0);
    println!("Nanos: {}", nanos.0);
}

I get the following warning from rustc:
warning: unnecessary `unsafe` block
 --> src/main.rs:9:9
  |
9 |         unsafe { Nanoseconds(0) }
  |         ^^^^^^ unnecessary `unsafe` block
  |
  = note: `#[warn(unused_unsafe)]` on by default

warning: `test_nanos` (bin "test_nanos") generated 1 warning
    Finished `dev` profile [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.00s
     Running `target/debug/test_nanos`
Nanos: 0

Since Nanoseconds is just a tuple struct, it should work to instantiate it without a surrounding unsafe block, right?

Because the #[rustc_layout_scalar_valid_range_*(…)] attributes tell the compiler it can optimize1 code based on the assumption that the value stored in a Nanoseconds never is outside the bounds. Therefore it is undefined behavior (UB) to create a Nanoseconds with a value outside the bounds:
#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Hash)]
#[repr(transparent)]
#[rustc_layout_scalar_valid_range_start(0)]
#[rustc_layout_scalar_valid_range_end(999_999_999)]
struct Nanoseconds(u32);

The relevant section in the reference about UB:


Producing an invalid value, even in private fields and locals. "Producing" a value happens any time a value is assigned to or read from a place, passed to a function/primitive operation or returned from a function/primitive operation. The following values are invalid (at their respective type):

[…]

Invalid values for a type with a custom definition of invalid values. In the standard library, this affects NonNull<T> and NonZero*.
Note: rustc achieves this with the unstable rustc_layout_scalar_valid_range_* attributes.





The compiler is allowed to assume the value in Nanoseconds is always within 0..=999_999_999 and optimizes accordingly.
That's similar to bool for example which occupies a whole byte, but only the values 0 and 1 are allowed while 2..=255 are invalid values.

1) For example it can omit bounds checks like nanos.0 <= 999_999_999, or it can use 1_000_000_000 and up as a nieche in an enum

So, the unsafety stems from those layout macros?

Yes, from the optimizations they allow.

@RichardNeumann They also allow niches.
